# How to minimize json in webpack?

Tags: json, webpack

I use [json-loader](https://github.com/webpack/json-loader) to load some data from `.json` file. This file is not minimized and I would like to not doing so, because it will be easier to maintain and update later.

However, it would be great if loaded file is minimalized by webpack in build.

```
// Part of webpack config
resolve: {
  extensions: ['', '.json']
},
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.json$/,
      loader: 'json-loader'
    }
  ]
}

// This file contains a lot of '\n's and '\t's
var someData = require('./someData');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this plugins:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

  module: { ... },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    })
  ]
```

Edit (due to OP comment):
Im not tested it but if you look at your loader https://github.com/webpack/json-loader/blob/master/index.js it add '\t' for readability. 
If you don't find any other module maybe you can write your loader similar to json-loader but with one change:

```
return "module.exports = " + JSON.stringify(value, undefined) + ";";
```

Comment: Still have a lot of \n